# Requirejs is looking in wrong path

Tags: requirejs

This is a config file in the `/themes/ifd/js/` folder:

```
require.config({
    // Initialize the application with the main application file
    deps: ['plugins/console', 'main'],
    baseUrl: '/themes/ifd/js/components'
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery/jquery.min',
        flexslider: 'flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min',
        easydropdown: 'easydropdown/jquery.easydropdown.min',
        bpopup: 'bpopup/jquery.bpopup.min',
        jqrangeslider: 'jqrangeslider/jQRangeSlider',
        jqueryui: 'jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min'
        // More additional paths here
    },
    shim: {
        jqueryui: 'jquery'
    },
    // Prevent caching issues, by adding an additional URL argument
    urlArgs: 'bust=' + (new Date()).getDate()
});
```

I've got a main.js file in the `/themes/ifd/js` folder too:

```
require([
    // Require the modules
    'modules/module',
    'jquery',
    'flexslider',
    'easydropdown',
    'bpopup',
    'jqueryui',
    'jqrangeslider'
], function (module) {
    'use strict';
    // Rest of a file
```

And rest of files (modules?) are inside `/themes/ifd/js/components`:

[Screenshot of list of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OXc8.png)

In my HTML I have:

```
<script data-main="/themes/ifd/js/main" src="/themes/ifd/js/requirejs.js"></script>
```

The messages I see in Chrome console:

```
GET http://DOMAIN/themes/ifd/js/jquery.js 404 (Not Found) requirejs.js:34
GET http://DOMAIN/themes/ifd/js/flexslider.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I can't find what is wrong and why it doesn't search in components directory...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entry point for requirejs is the main module specified in the html file.

```
<script data-main="/themes/ifd/js/main" src="/themes/ifd/js/requirejs.js"></script>
```

requirejs loads '/themes/ifd/js/main.js' 1st. Now in the main.js file, require([...]) try to load in the module specified in the args but requirejs won't be able to find them.

The reason is that requirejs does not know about them since require.config (...) is not executed.

Need to have 'require.config (...)' in '/themes/ifd/js/main.js' to do all the settings

Here is a [working example](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette). It includes Requirejs, jQueryMobile, Backbone, and Marinonette.

In the [index.html](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette/blob/master/js/main.js) file, you need to specify the main module for requirejs to load.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
```

In this example, the main module is under ["js/main.js"](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette/blob/master/index.html)

Inside, main.js, you specify the require.config and use define to load your modules.

Comment: Thanks, both yours solutions are good. Now i've got other problems but that perticular problem is considered as solved :)

Answer (score 1):

The network activity you show us indicates that your configuration is *completely* ignored by RequireJS. And you say "Then i have that in my html":

```
<script data-main="/themes/ifd/js/main" src="/themes/ifd/js/requirejs.js"></script>
```

You've shown the contents of `/themes/ifd/js/main.js` but it does not include your configuration, which apparently is in a different file.

The solution here would be to move your call to `require.config` into your `main.js` file, before your call to `require`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just loading `main.js` and never telling RequireJS to use your config.

This RequireJS [issue](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/354) lists several ways to load both a config and a main -

> 1. put the config on the HTML before you require the top-level module.
> 2. load the config.js with another  tag.
> 3. do a nested require() on the HTML file (require config than require your main).
> 4. do a nested require() inside main.js.
> 5. keep the configuration inside main.js
>
> The best approach will vary based on your project structure, I've been doing 5 way more often than the others since I usually have a single entry-point for all pages, but in some cases I used 1 and 2.

Further down the page some code examples of these approaches are also shown.